# A self-referential puzzle

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

This puzzle uses X characters of text. Can you replace "X" with the correct number? Spaces and punctuation are counted too. Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of characters in the text

> excluding the first X, add up to 133. (I feel that the question implies that we have to replace only the first X, not both of the X's.)

But that is not yet final.

> 133 would still not work because we add 3 new characters (1, 3, and 2) when replacing the first X.

Therefore

> because the number of characters is now 133+3 = 136, then there is no harm in changing X = 133 to **X = 136** since the number of added characters would not change when doing so.

Comment: Will edit my answer, because I feel I messed up at one part.

Comment: I helped you to improve your answer more.

Comment: wait fricc, I did not notice the rest of the edit. @CulverKwan there are 3 characters added when you replace X with 133, are there not? :0 I think you have to count the repeats as well..

Comment: X to 135, which means there are two characters more. Originally, X has 1 character, and 135 has 3 characters, so it has increased 3-1=2 characters. You can count it again.

Comment: ah shucks, you do have a point. that's nice then :0

Comment: You got it. Well done!

Comment: @CulverKwan The count of 133 does not include the first X. oAlt had it right.

Comment: @DanielMathias nope, i realized my mistake as well. let me explain fully: if we count all the characters excluding the first X, it comes to 133 characters. so far, you are right about what you said. now again, 133 would not work because we're still adding characters. but how many characters have we "added"? rephrasing what Culver Kwan said, if we replace X with three characters, it would just be like replacing X with one of the characters and then adding the other two. indeed, the net change in characters is just 2, and that is why the answer must be 135 :0

Comment: "Excluding the first X" means that the X is *not counted* as one of the 133 characters. Replacing the X takes the total from 133+1 to 133+3.

Comment: ok hold on, how did i miss this. @DanielMathias u are correct, and i'm really sorry if u got confused.

Comment: sorry for my confusion as well; i forgot to consider that the first X was not part of the 133. will @DmitryKamenetsky confirm?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0b10001010? rot13: Gurer ner gjb Kf abg bar

Comment: The answer above is correct.

Comment: I give you a new challenge though. I can't write it in the original puzzle as it will ruin it. What happens if X is allowed to have leading zeroes? ;)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know if anything special is going to happen, but you can still adjust the digits after the leading zeroes :)

Answer (score 5):

Alternative solution:

> This puzzle uses one hundred fifty-five characters of text. Can you replace "X" with the correct number? Spaces and punctuation are counted too. Good luck!

Or, if you prefer *and*:

> This puzzle uses one hundred and fifty-nine characters of text. Can you replace "X" with the correct number? Spaces and punctuation are counted too. Good luck!

And just because I can:

> This answer uses one hundred fifty-five characters of text. I have replaced "X" with the correct number. Spaces and punctuation are counted too. Thank you!